# Snowflake Load history

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have found 4 ways to see the load history in Snowflake:

```
SELECT * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."COPY_HISTORY"

SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."LOAD_HISTORY"

SELECT * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."LOAD_HISTORY"

SELECT * FROM "DATABASE_NAME"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."LOAD_HISTORY"
```

What are the differences between these and when should each be used (or not used) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> SELECT * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."COPY_HISTORY"
```

This is an **Account Usage** view that is used to query data loading history for the last 365 days, for both batch loading (`COPY INTO <table>`) and continuous loading (with Snowpipe).
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/copy_history.html#copy-history-view

```
> SELECT * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."LOAD_HISTORY"
```

This is also an **Account Usage** view, but excludes files loaded with Snowpipe. This view may also be subject to latency of up to 90 mins.

```
> SELECT * FROM "DATABASE_NAME"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."LOAD_HISTORY"
```

This is an **Information Schema** view that is used to query the history of data loaded into tables using the `COPY INTO <table>` command within the last 14 days. The view displays one row for each file loaded, does *not* include data loaded with Snowpipe.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/load_history.html#load-history-view

```
> SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."LOAD_HISTORY"
```

This is just a specific example of the previous one, but since the `Snowflake` database is a system defined, shared, read-only database, querying this view probably won't return anything (useful).

Answer (score 3):

The difference between account_usage and information_schema is well-documented here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema

The key being the amount of history, the latency, and the access control.

The difference between `COPY_HISTORY` and `LOAD_HISTORY` is that `COPY_HISTORY` include SNOWPIPE ingested data, while the `LOAD_HISTORY` only includes data loaded via a `COPY INTO` statement.

The last one is the `LOAD_HISTORY` of the `SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  This will most likely be empty as it would reflect the load history of data into that database/schema and since that is a shared database to customers from Snowflake, you won't see anything in there.

Comment: Thanks ! Since COPY_HISTORY can easily be queried to get just the `COPY INTO` results, and since LOAD_HISTORY seems to have latency issues as well as a smaller window of history, I can't see the reason for using LOAD_HISTORY at all - am I missing something ?

Comment: Not sure I'm following.  Both have 1 year of data in account_usage, but the latency of the `LOAD_HISTORY` is actually a bit less than `COPY_HISTORY`, so it really just depends on what you're looking for.  I would also think that the queries against `LOAD_HISTORY` might be a bit faster, since there are fewer records there....assuming you're using SNOWPIPE, that is.